# How to save text to speech to audio file in android

Tags: android, text-to-speech, android-mediaplayer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to store text to speech output as WAV file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14683559/how-to-store-text-to-speech-output-as-wav-file)

I am working TTS conversation. In my application I need to save the speech as audio file. As per my requirements I need to play TTS output with MediaPlayer, that is the reason I am asking you guys, how can I make tts to audio file and then play using Mediaplayer. Can anyone help on this? if there is any code snippet? that is really very helpful.

Thanks in advance,
Chandra.